# How can I get first component of type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get the first *MonoBehaviour component* to run a *public void function*.
I actually use `ObjectReference.GetComponent<ComponentName>().FunctionName();` but it would take me so much time because there's multiple *ObjectReference* and that implicates that I can't use the same script name with diff source.

Comment: I don't use Unity so I'm not sure whether this is some scenario specific to that but normally you would put all your objects in a list and call `First` or, if it might be empty, `FirstOrDefault`. Does that apply here?

Comment: @user18387401 thanks for your suggestion but in this case that approach won't work.  In Unity, "components" are attached to `GameObject`s of which there many (and have dynamic lifetimes) and each `GameObject` can have 1..n components.  It's awesome, you should check it out :)

Comment: If you use interfaces you could do something like [`var item = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<ISomethingOfInterest>().First()`](https://answers.unity.com/questions/863509/how-can-i-find-all-objects-that-have-a-script-that.html).  Be warned though, **this [function is very slow. It is not recommended to use this function every frame](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)**

Comment: Why do you need to get first MonoBehaviour?

Comment: @oistikbal The playerCamera detects objects with a tag called "Interactive". After you interact with them it will run the first script's public void (to clarify, the first script found in the interactable object).

Comment: You don't need to get the first MonoBehaviour. When interaction happens use `Component.TryGetComponent` on the interaction object. this will also make tag check unnecessary. Check [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html](docs)

Comment: @oistikbal Thank you so much! It actually gets the script but how would I run a public void? I'd try with `FoundScript.FunctionName();` but I got error CS1061.

Comment: `if (hit.collider.tag == "Interactive Object")
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    print(hit.collider);
                    print(hit.collider.transform);
                    if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out MonoBehaviour FoundScript))
                    {
                        Debug.Log(FoundScript.GetType().GetMethod("Interact"));
                    }`

Comment: You can't call your method via MonoBehaviour, you should get the type of your custom class, it's also MonoBehaviour. then you will be able to call your method. You should check how inheritance works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here, thank you all for helping!!! https://answers.unity.com/questions/376676/accessing-a-script-without-knowing-its-name.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).